# Mandar stream de datos a inputs dentro de un ngFor

Tags: html, angular, formularios, rxjs

Me ha surgido una duda para encontrar la mejor vía para solucionar el siguiente caso.

Tengo un componente **A** que es padre de 2 componentes hijos: el componente **app-select** que es un select desplegable al que le pasamos sus valores mediante el input "options" y el componente **app-cajavalores**  que se repetirá 5 veces, según el array "items", mediante un bucle **ngFor**. El template del componente padre básicamente es este:

```
<div class="card-body">
    <app-select (onSelect)="suscribirTopic($event)" [options]="selectables"></app-select>
    <app-cajavalores *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">{{etiquetasLabel[i]}}</app-cajavalores>
</div>
```

Como podéis ver, estoy usando un segundo array llamado **etiquetasLabel** que usa el index para dar valor a la etiqueta `<label>` de cada componente hijo **app-cajavalores**.

La pinta que tiene el template del componente **app-cajavalores** es la siguiente:

```
<label>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
    <input type="text" value="--" readOnly="true">
</label>
```

La duda se presenta en este momento. La mecánica es la siguiente: cuando selecciono un valor de la lista desplegable del primer hijo se dispara el evento **suscribirTopic($event)** en el padre. Este evento se suscribirá a un topic o cola de mensajes gestionado en un broker de mensajería que comenzará a devolver un stream de valores asíncrono.

Cada mensaje que reciba del stream contendrá un nombre y un valor, el nombre coincidirá con una de las 5 etiquetas `<label>` generadas en el bucle y el valor será un número que deberá aparecer en el `<input>` asignado a dicho `<label>`, pero no se de qué manera puedo identificar estos campos para que cada valor recibido del stream se muestre en su correspondiente `<input>`.

No logro visualizar la mejor manera de discriminar el componente **app-cajavalores** al que enlazar el valor del mensaje recibido ni de qué manera mostrarlo en el `<input>`. Entiendo que de alguna manera habría que comprobar que el valor "nombre" recibido en cada mensaje sea igual o no a la etiqueta `<label>` de cada componente generado o algo similar...

Comment: Hola, puedes hacer un ejemplo funcional en [stackblitz](https://www.stackblitz.com)? Solo la parte funcional, de esa manera sera mas facil entender tu problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De la misma forma que a cada componente `app-cajavalores` le incorporas un contenido para el label, podrías tambien entregarle el valor para el input:

```
<app-cajavalores
    [valor]="valores[i]"
    *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index"> 
    {{etiquetasLabel[i]}}
</app-cajavalores>
```

app-cajavalores html:

```
<label>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
    <input type="text" [value]="valor" readOnly="true">
</label>
```

El arreglo de valores entonces estaria definido en el componente padre y lo completarias a medida que el servicio que mencionas los retorne.